# How to Do a Jacobs Ladder Search in OracleDB?

Tags: sql, oracle

Not sure if this is even possible in OracleDB but I thought it was worth a shot. I am looking to search through a single table which has data stored in a Jacobs Ladder format.

Each piece of data has a old and a new code. The new code for one old code can also be a old code for another new code. I need the newest code, meaning an old code with no new code assigned. The tricky part is that i also need the oldest code + the newest code. Nothing in between. It's a little easier to explain with an example..

I do not have the first clue on beginning to create some complete very complicated query like this. any info is a lot of help.

For Example:

```
Old Code | New Code | New Code Info
A123     | B697     | New Code Info
D323     |          | New Code Info
B697     | X123     | New Code Info
G222     | S122     | New Code Info
S122     |          | New Code Info
T832     |          | New Code Info
X123     |          | New Code Info
```

Expected Result:

```
Old Code | New Code | New Code Info
A123     | X123     | New Code Info
D323     | D323     | New Code Info
G222     | S122     | New Code Info
T832     | T832     | New Code Info
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [a hierarchical query](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Hierarchical-Queries.html), working backwards from the entries with no new code, and tracking the code and info from the starting rows:

```
-- CTE for sample data
with your_table (old_code, new_code, new_code_info) as (
            select 'A123', 'B697', 'New Code Info 1' from dual
  union all select 'D323', null, 'New Code Info 2' from dual
  union all select 'B697', 'X123', 'New Code Info 3' from dual
  union all select 'G222', 'S122', 'New Code Info 4' from dual
  union all select 'S122', null, 'New Code Info 5' from dual
  union all select 'T832', null, 'New Code Info 6' from dual
  union all select 'X123', null, 'New Code Info 7' from dual
)
-- actual query
select old_code, new_code, new_code_info,
  level as lvl,
  connect_by_root (old_code) as root_old_code,
  connect_by_root(new_code_info) as root_new_code_info
from your_table
start with new_code is null
connect by new_code = prior old_code;

OLD_ NEW_ NEW_CODE_INFO          LVL ROOT ROOT_NEW_CODE_I
---- ---- --------------- ---------- ---- ---------------
D323      New Code Info 2          1 D323 New Code Info 2
S122      New Code Info 5          1 S122 New Code Info 5
G222 S122 New Code Info 4          2 S122 New Code Info 5
T832      New Code Info 6          1 T832 New Code Info 6
X123      New Code Info 7          1 X123 New Code Info 7
B697 X123 New Code Info 3          2 X123 New Code Info 7
A123 B697 New Code Info 1          3 X123 New Code Info 7

7 rows selected.
```

And then use that as a CTE or inline view and group/filter the results, so you only keep the highest level, here [using `last()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/LAST.html#):

```
select max(old_code) keep (dense_rank last order by lvl) as old_code,
  root_old_code as new_code,
  root_new_code_info as new_code_info
from (
  select old_code, new_code, new_code_info,
    level as lvl,
    connect_by_root (old_code) as root_old_code,
    connect_by_root(new_code_info) as root_new_code_info
  from your_table
  start with new_code is null
  connect by new_code = prior old_code
)
group by root_old_code, root_new_code_info
order by old_code;

OLD_ NEW_ NEW_CODE_INFO  
---- ---- ---------------
A123 X123 New Code Info 7
D323 D323 New Code Info 2
G222 S122 New Code Info 5
T832 T832 New Code Info 6
```

Or you could do it in a single step with [`connect_by_isleaf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Hierarchical-Query-Pseudocolumns.html#GUID-7DFBC564-31A6-4C71-A79C-6D3CC0B0BB10), which is a similar idea internally I suppose:

```
select old_code,
  connect_by_root (old_code) as new_code,
  connect_by_root(new_code_info) as root_new_code_info
from your_table
where connect_by_isleaf = 1
start with new_code is null
connect by new_code = prior old_code
order by old_code;

OLD_ NEW_ ROOT_NEW_CODE_I
---- ---- ---------------
A123 X123 New Code Info 7
D323 D323 New Code Info 2
G222 S122 New Code Info 5
T832 T832 New Code Info 6
```

Comment: I am going to assume this is the answer. I need to to some research on a few of the things you suggested then update my post. Thanks a ton for the answer!

Comment: I've added a few links, if anything is unclear I can expand on it a bit. Not sure what you mean about updating your post (question) though. Yo don't normally need or want to add things from an answer into a question.